# performance warning when using glMapBufferRange

Tags: c++, opengl

When i try to update an array buffer using `glMapBufferRange`, the data updates but as soon as the next draw of the buffer occurs a performance warning is generated (via `glDebugMessageCallback`) as follows:

> "Buffer performance warning: Buffer object 3 (bound to
>   GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (0),
>   GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (1),
>   GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (2),
>   GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (3), and
>   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STREAM_DRAW) is being
>   copied/moved from VIDEO memory to HOST memory."

I create the array buffer as follows:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSizeBytes, vertData,GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

Then i update with replacement vertex data:

```
//NO PERFORMANCE WARNING IF I USE glBufferSubData
//glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, dataSizeBytes, vertData);

float* dataBlock = reinterpret_cast<float*>(
    glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,
    dataSizeBytes,
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT));

memcpy(dataBlock, vertData, dataSizeBytes);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

As soon as `glDrawElements` is called for this buffer the performance warning is generated.  I tried removing the unsynchronized flag and the invalidate flag but those didnt seem to make a difference.

I assume im doing something wrong but im not sure what it is.  The code still works and draws everything correctly (but i see that performance warning which irks me). As commented `glBufferSubData` doesnt generate any warning, but `glMapBufferRange` triggers the error (after draw).

If i try to update the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` i get a similar performance warning.

---

UPDATE 1:
If I allocate the data with `GL_STREAM_DRAW` or `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` I get the performance warning. If I use `GL_STATIC_DRAW` I get no warning.  However this vertex buffer is meant to be updated every frame.  If I use `glBufferSubData` I get no warning regardless of the storage hint.

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want the driver to do? Also, are you able to use `glBufferStorage` to create the buffer?

Comment: @Nicol I would like it to allocate the storage it needs wherever it decides is best (and hopefully fastest) and leave it there i suppose? Im assuming the warning is because it moves it.  The fact that theres no warning if i use glBufferSubData kind of bothers me too , which makes me think i should just use that.  I will look into glBufferStorage.

Comment: "*I would like it to allocate the storage it needs wherever it decides is best (and hopefully fastest) and leave it there i suppose?*" It can't know whether you're going to upload to the buffer or map-and-write to it until you actually try to do one of them. That's standard for dealing with buffer objects in OpenGL, and that's why they invented [immutable storage buffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage).

Comment: And FYI, no they can't just listen to the usage hints, because people have so misused those hints that they've become negatively useful to implementations. Also because different implementations give them very different behaviors.